# Rebuilding docker image is failing although using the same Dockerfile as shown in the hub

Tags: node.js, docker, nightmare

I would like to build this docker image by myself: chrisgeorge/nightmare-headless (https://hub.docker.com/r/chrisgeorge/nightmare-headless/~/dockerfile/)

So I used the same Dockerfile.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        xvfb \
        x11-xkb-utils \
        xfonts-100dpi \
        xfonts-75dpi \ 
        xfonts-scalable \
        xfonts-cyrillic \
        x11-apps \
        clang \
        libdbus-1-dev \
        libgtk2.0-dev \
        libnotify-dev \
        libgnome-keyring-dev \
        libgconf2-dev \
        libasound2-dev \
        libcap-dev \
        libcups2-dev \
        libxtst-dev \
        libxss1 \
        libnss3-dev \
        gcc-multilib \
        g++-multilib \
        xauth \
        git \
        sudo \
        --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get autoclean \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/api/lists/*

RUN chown -R node:node /home/node
RUN echo %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL >> /etc/sudoers
WORKDIR /home/node
ENV HOME /home/node
USER node
RUN npm install nightmare
```

`npm install nightmare` will call `npm install electron` and this is failing:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/install.js:47
  throw err
  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/dist/resources'
    at Error (native)
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "electron"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! electron@1.6.6 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Comment: This looks like a new bug in electron's releases today. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706749/could-not-install-electron-in-windows-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking this happens because the versions of the dependencies in the dockerfile are not specified.

An application can break if its dependencies have a different version than what it was developed with. It's best practice to set the version of most dependencies in the dockerfile so that `apt install` actually installs the same software all the time. Some exceptions exist like curl used for a healthcheck which will almost 100% work after an update too

Answer (score 1):

Update: this should now be fixed - https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9323#issuecomment-298287399

---

This is a bug in a dependency of Electron, there is a [workaround](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9323#issuecomment-298205377):

> add "extract-zip": "=1.6.0", to your project's package.json dependencies in the same place where electron dependency located.